# Find a sequence of functions in $L^1$ with a given properties

Tags: lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

Give an example of a sequence of functions ($ f_n \epsilon L^1 ([0,1])$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$) and a function $g\epsilon L^1 ([0,1])$ with the following properties.

a.  $ f_n (x) \rightarrow g(x) $ for almost all $x\epsilon [0,1]$

b.  $\int_{[0,1]} |f_n|d \lambda = 2 $ for every $n=1,2,3... $

c.  $\int_{[0,1]} |g|d \lambda = 1 $

I am having difficulty even picturing the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $g=1$ and $f_{n}=1+(n+1)x^{n}$, then $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}[0,1]}=2$ and $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 1$ for all $x\in[0,1)$.

Comment: thanks, I was close but was have trouble with the details of f